# js с JQuery и без JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

В чем его смысл, если можно писать на чистом js и обходиться без него ? Можете привести пожалуйста примеры

Comment: [Зачем нам jQuery?](https://habr.com/ru/company/piter/blog/308134/)

Comment: jQuery в древние времена предоставлял разработчикам разные плюшки, которые сейчас и так есть в чистом JS..

Comment: У jQuery есть хорошая поддержка для старых браузеров. (Бонусом к комментарию @Jour)

Comment: В 2023 году jQuery не нужен

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery представляет собой библиотеку JavaScript, которая предоставляет удобный способ взаимодействия с HTML-документами, а также множество полезных методов и функций для работы со страницей веб-сайта. Он упрощает работу с **DOM (Document Object Model)**, а также позволяет создавать анимации, работать с сетью и многое другое.

Одним из основных преимуществ `jQuery` является то, что он позволяет упростить синтаксис `JavaScript` и сделать код более читаемым. Например, с помощью `jQuery` можно легко найти элементы на странице и изменить их содержимое:

```
$('.my-element').html('Hello, World!');
```

Без jQuery это бы выглядело так:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.my-element').forEach(function(el) {
  el.innerHTML = 'Hello, World!';
});
```

jQuery позволяет упростить работу с событиями на странице, такими как нажатие кнопки, наведение мыши и т.д.:

```
$('.my-button').click(function() {
  console.log('Button was clicked!');
})
```

Да, также jQuery предоставляет удобный механизм для взаимодействия с сетью, что позволяет легко отправлять AJAX-запросы и обрабатывать ответы сервера. Например, вы можете отправить GET-запрос на сервер с помощью следующего кода:

```
$.get('/some/url', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Без jQuery это бы выглядело так:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/some/url');
xhr.onload = function() {
  console.log(xhr.response);
};
xhr.send();
```

Кроме того, jQuery имеет множество дополнительных функций и методов, которые могут быть очень полезны в разработке веб-приложений. Некоторые из них:

- `$.each` - позволяет итерировать по массиву или объекту
- `$.extend` - позволяет слить несколько объектов в один
- `$.inArray` - проверяет, содержится ли элемент в массиве
- `$.isEmptyObject` - проверяет, является ли объект пустым
- `$.trim` - удаляет пробелы из начала и конца строки
- `$.proxy` - создает новую функцию с замкнутым контекстом

Например, можно использовать $.each для итерации по массиву чисел и вывода их на экран:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

$.each(numbers, function(index, value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Без jQuery это бы выглядело так:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

numbers.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

В целом, jQuery может быть очень полезен для упрощения работы с JavaScript и увеличения эффективности разработки. Однако, также стоит помнить, что в некоторых случаях чистый JavaScript может быть более эффективным и производительным. В общем, выбор между jQuery и чистым JavaScript зависит от конкретных целей и потребностей проекта.

В jQuery также есть методы для работы с анимацией, что может быть очень полезно для создания динамичных интерактивных сайтов. Например, метод $.animate позволяет изменять свойства CSS элемента с помощью анимации:

```
$('.my-element').animate({
  width: '100px',
  height: '100px',
  opacity: 0.5
}, 500);
```

В этом примере элемент с классом `my-element` будет анимированно изменять свои размеры и прозрачность в течение 500 миллисекунд.

Кроме того, jQuery также имеет методы для работы с событиями на странице, такими как нажатие кнопки, наведение мыши, изменение размера окна и т.д. Например, метод `$.click` позволяет выполнять функцию при нажатии на элемент:

```
$('.my-button').click(function() {
  console.log('Button was clicked!');
});
```

Без jQuery это бы выглядело так:

```
var button = document.querySelector('.my-button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('Button was clicked!');
});
```

---

В JavaScript существует функция `fetch`, которая позволяет делать HTTP-запросы к серверу. Она может быть полезна в случаях, когда вы хотите избежать использования библиотеки, такой как jQuery, или когда вам нужно работать с функциями `fetch API` напрямую. Например, вы можете отправить GET-запрос с помощью следующего кода:

```
fetch('/some/url')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Касательно анимаций, вы правы, что они могут быть созданы с помощью CSS. В этом случае нет необходимости использовать jQuery или другую библиотеку. Однако, иногда может быть удобно анимировать элементы с помощью JavaScript, например, когда нужно управлять событиями.

jQuery имеет множество методов для работы с событиями на странице. Одним из них является метод `$.on`, который позволяет назначить событие на элемент. Например, можно использовать его для назначения события нажатия на элемент:

```
$('.my-element').on('click', function() {
  console.log('Element was clicked!');
});
```

Этот код будет выполнять функцию при нажатии на любой элемент с классом `my-element`. Метод `$.on` также позволяет назначать события на элементы, которые будут добавлены в DOM в будущем. Например:

```
$('.my-container').on('click', '.my-element', function() {
  console.log('Element was clicked!');
});
```

В этом случае событие будет назначено на все элементы с классом `my-element`

Comment: Вместо последнего примера может быть практичнее использовать какой-нибудь [delegated-events](https://github.com/dgraham/delegated-events) или аналог, чтобы не тащить монструозный jQuery

Comment: @andreymal самый главный плюс jQuery это то что в нем нет зависимостей в рантайм. delegated-events зависит от библиотеки, которая переведена в паблик-архив.

Comment: @eri примерно поэтому я и написал «или аналог»

Comment: Если нужно встроить какой нибудь элемент в пхп сайт и нужно сделать больше чем одну фишку - выберу jQuery потому как альтернатива этому это ещё большее зло react, angular, vue или очень много маленьких скриптов. Хорошо что эти задачки удалось спихнуть на пхпшника)))

Comment: не все свойства можно анимировать с помощью css, в отличие от `animate`